# If in an excel sheet, a certain value is not found then append a zero to using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

```py
files = glob.glob (r'C:\test\Phase 1A\*.xlsm')
for file in files:
    print(file)

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file,data_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == "Vessel Volume":#search for Volume
                idxr=cell.row #where idxr is the index of the row
                idxc=cell.column #where idxc is the index of the column
                a=ws.cell(idxr,idxc+1).value
            elif cell.value == "Phase":#search for Phase
                idxr=cell.row
                idxc=cell.column
                b=ws.cell(idxr,idxc+1).value    
            elif cell.value == "Test#":#search for Test#
                idxr=cell.row
                idxc=cell.column
                c=ws.cell(idxr,idxc+1).value    
            elif cell.value == "Concentration":#search for Concentration
                idxr=cell.row
                idxc=cell.column
                d=ws.cell(idxr,idxc+1).value
            elif cell.value == "Time Delay":#search for Time Delay
                idxr=cell.row
                idxc=cell.column
                e=ws.cell(idxr,idxc+1).value
            elif cell.value == "Pstat\nEffective":#search for Pred by locating Pstat Effective
                idxr=cell.row
                idxc=cell.column
                f=ws.cell(idxr+1,idxc+4).value
            elif cell.value == "NON Existent":
                idxr=cell.row
                idxc=cell.column
                g=ws.cell(idxr,idxc).value
                g1.append(g)
    a1.append(a)
    b1.append(b)
    c1.append(c)
    d1.append(d)
    e1.append(e)
    f1.append(f)
```

Hello, I am beginner at python and openpyxl.

I would like to create equal size arrays(or lists) a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1 and g1.In my code I look for certain expressions in cells of a list of excel files and I append them in the arrays.

I have an issue only with variable g. The string "NON Existent" it exists only to some of the xlsm files. I want every time that there is no such a string in the whole excel file to get ont time g=0 or 'N/A' to my array and append it.

Many thanks for any help that you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to check the length of `g1` at the end. If it is zero, then you know that there were no 'NON Existent' values in the sheet.

```
# After your other appends...    
e1.append(e)
f1.append(f)
if len(g1)==0:
        # Do whatever here...
```

There are more elegant ways, but this is nice and simple.

Note: Assuming `g1` is defined somewhere else in the code, not shown here, because you can't append to something that hasn't been defined yet.